# JQuery Return the Object with the Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I've got multiple pages of widgets. The contents of the widgets are static, though their display can change. I need to be able to store these, so I'm building an multi-dimensional object.

I need to store the object and display the object.

Here's a simplified version of my factory:

```js
const createWidget = ({
   id    = undefined,
   name  = 'new widget',
   style = 'vertical_list',
   html  = undefined,

} = {}) => ({
   id,
   name,
   style,
   data,
   
   constructWidget () {
     return $.ajax({
        url: '/my/url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            '_token'   : window.xsrf_token,
            'widget_id': this.id,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).then(reponse => {
        let widget = response.widget;
        this.name  = widget.name;
        this.style = widget.style;
        this.html  = widget.html;
    });
  },
})
```

That hydrates the object with everything just fine, but I can't get the object back.

```js
let book      = {};
let page      = 'example page';
book[page]    = book[page] || {};
let widget_id = 88;

// TRYING TO STORE
// this just give me the promise and I can't get at the object :(
book[page][widget_id] = CreateWidget({id: widget_id}).constructWidget();  


// TRYING TO DISPLAY
let widget = book[page][widget_id];
$(`#current_page`).append(`
    <div id="widget_${widget.id}" class="${style}">
      <b>${widget.name}</b>
      ${widget.html}
    </div>`
 );
```

So? Why is this approach stupid and how do I fix it? I've tried messing with promises a bunch, but without access to the hydrated object I can't seem to do a dang thing.

Comment: Where is `createWidget` called? Also no parameter is defined for either `constructWidget_1` or `constructWidget_2` functions, though `{id: widget_id}` is passed as parameter.

Comment: you need to understand that Promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous. `CreateWidget_1({id: widget_id}).then(x => ...)` x could be what you need, if only you returned it

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, that was dumb. I've been banging my head on this code too long. Fixed the example.

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX, I've got that. What I don't have is how to get to an object that has a promise as a method in an asynch way.

Comment: so, something like https://jsfiddle.net/32bpj3e4/

Comment: of course, you can't just `let book = {}; book[page][widget_id] = ....` - you have to "create" the intermediate `book[page]`

Comment: @guest271314 ... ***something like*** - there are bound to be easy to fix typos - https://jsfiddle.net/32bpj3e4/2/

Comment: @guest271314 - but `createWidget({ id: widget_id }).constructWidget()` does - read the code

Comment: I basically copied the code in the question, removed the second "construct" code as that was very wrong, forgot to rename some stuff, didn't check the original codes typos, and added a much needed `return this` - so, bound to be SOME typos in there seeing as the original code would actually fail and not even, as the OP claims `hydrates the object with everything just fine` - there are fundamental errors that would prevent this code from running at all

Comment: Hey @JaromandaX thanks for bearing with me through the typos. The actual code is fairly complex, so I was trying to quickly simplify it. I've literally been at this for a full day. I've obviously read some stupid articles because at some point I read that a return inside a `then()` was meaningless. That along with the await bit worked. I'll clean up my code, but if you want to throw that fiddle into an answer I'd like to chose that as the answer.

Comment: I should mention that the `constructWidget_2()` was meant to `return this` and not the promise. It obviously isn't right, but that's what I was trying to illustrate... that I was screwing up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to return `this` as part of the promise. I wasn't doing that. Huge thanks to @JaromandaX for that.

Returning the promise and the object means that I continue on a asynchronous path. Simplified example answer below.

```js
const createWidget = ({
   id    = undefined,
   name  = 'new widget',
   style = 'vertical_list',
   html  = undefined,

} = {}) => ({
   id,
   name,
   style,
   data,
   
   constructWidget () {
     return $.ajax({
        url : '/my/url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            '_token'   : window.xsrf_token,
            'widget_id': this.id,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).then(reponse => {
        let widget = response.widget;
        this.name  = widget.name;
        this.style = widget.style;
        this.html  = widget.html;
        return this; // <-- here's what I was missing.
    });
  },
}) 


let book      = {};
let page      = 'example page';
book[page]    = book[page] || {};
let widget_id = 88;

CreateWidget({id: widget_id})
  .constructWidget()
  .then(widget => {
    book[page][widget_id] = widget;
    $(`#current_page`).append(`
       <div id="widget_${widget.id}" class="${style}">
         <b>${widget.name}</b>
         ${widget.html}
       </div>`
    ); 
  })
  .fail(error => console.error);
```

A pox upon the article that said a return inside the `then` was meaningless!

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait for these promises somehow

simplest (well, the shorter code example at least) way is to use async/await

```
async function() {
  book[page][widget_id] = await CreateWidget_1({id: widget_id}) //the promise :(
  book[page][widget_id] = await CreateWidget_2({id: widget_id}) //maybe...
  $(`#current_page`).append(`<div>${book[page][widget_id]}</div>`); //nope, that'll be undefined because the promise isn't complete this isn't an asynch approach, dummy
```

or the longer promises based

```
Promise.all[CreateWidget_1(...), CreateWidget_2(...)])
  .then(function() { $(`#current_page`).append(...) })
```

Also, chaining is one of the most important concepts of promises, to properly use promise, they need to be returned, both your functions need to return the promise (only one returns it)

Comment: the only issue with this ... neither `constructWidget_1` nor `constructWidget_2` return anything useful

Comment: `only one returns it` - sure, but it returns a promise that resolves to `undefined`

Comment: adding `return this` after `this.data = widget.data;` in `constructWidget_1` will help

Comment: in this case it doesn't matter what it resolves to, because they manipulate some external object, which is obviously not a good approach but I didn't want to overwhelm

Comment: How about "overwhelm" and let's do it right? I appreciate the _get it working_ sentiment, but _get it done right_ is always a better tune.